# Pop up over hover in a web page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a sub block in a pop up manner when the user hovers over a link. I could not find a proper way to get a display like the image provided below. Also, I would like to make that sub block clickable and workable. I am trying this using bootstrap and jquery, but, I am fairly new in these areas and not sure what exactly I should be doing. Can some one please help me with this thing?

[image]

Comment: @"Sirnath Sridhar" Something like http://www.bootply.com/Rc5gy7zt7R

Comment: Sorry I meant this http://www.bootply.com/k6vP5rxBEv

Comment: did the bootly help?

Comment: I tried below code. But it didnt work. Am i going wrong any where?
<html>
<head>
 <title>Home</title>
 <link type ="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link type ="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link type ="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
 <link type ="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script>
 $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
 </script>

Comment: </head>
<body>
 <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
  
<a href="#" class="" data-trigger="click" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Enter Data'/> <br/> <p> you can put any html content in here</p>" data-original-title="Popover Title">Click this link to toggle</a>

</div>  
</div> 
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Sirnath create a jsbin or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just working with hovers (not clicks), you can do it all with CSS. For example:

```
.hoverbox {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 200px;
    display: none;
}
a:hover + .hoverbox, .hoverbox:hover { display: block }
```

Just set it to be hidden, then unhide it when it's being hovered on, or it's followed by the link that's being hovered on. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsgsw3x3/)

You can increase the hover area using a wrapper div (.hoveroutside):

```
.hoverbox {
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 200px;
}
.hoveroutside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid red; /* Just for you to see */
}
a:hover + .hoveroutside, .hoveroutside:hover { display: block }
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsgsw3x3/1/)

Comment: I tried to run the script. But I couldn't able to hide it. So the content gets displayed before I hover it....

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially 3 steps to work on: build your block, recognize the hover event and then place and visualize your block near the link which triggered the hover event.

1-
You could build your block with a div containing all you block stuff and having initially a `display: none` prop and a `z-index` prop able to override the HTML elements initially visualized when you show the block.

2-
use JQuery to get the hover event on the link element you want , get the x,y position (use offset) of the element.

3-
set the "absolute position" of the block div using JavaScript or JQuery methods with the values you've gained in step 2.
Apply show method on div block.